# If element's child contains certain text (found in array)

Tags: jquery, arrays, navigation

The navigation system looks like below. What I want to do is to add menu items to an array, and to those items certain actions should be performed.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this hence I need your help, thanks!

html:

```
<ul id="mainnav-menu" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item menu-item-1">
        <a href="#">Apples</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item menu-item-2">
        <a href="#">Oranges</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item menu-item-3">
        <span class="submenu-dropdown-toggle"></span>
        <a href="#">Green bananas</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var performActionsTo = ['Apples', 'Oranges'];

$('.menu-item').each(function() {
    if $(this).closest('a').text() == /* exists in array */ {
        console.log('action');
    };
});
```

Comment: Have you search for it???

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yes, I have searched for it but haven't yet found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be made a lot simpler using jQuery's `contains` selector:

```
$.each(performActionsTo, function(i, val) {
  var element = $(".menu-item a:contains('" + val + "')");
  // Perform action on element
});
```

**Caveat:**

This answer (as with the other answers) could need extra attention if you decide to have `Apples` and then `Big Apples`, as the first will match both elements as both anchors will 'contain' the term.

Comment: @KarlSagar Did you try my answer?

Comment: @JohnR: Yes, I did. Unfortunately it only found one of the elements in the array by some reason. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @KarlSagar Okay. I have removed my answer.

Comment: @KarlSagar - no problem, out of curiosity - what is the 'action'?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: The action is to change the scr (href) of all of these links to a specific page.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var performActionsTo = ['Apples', 'Oranges'];
$('.menu-item').each(function() {
    if ( performActionsTo.indexOf($(this).find('a').text()) > -1) {
        console.log('action');
    };
});
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp